Why does this error occur while deploying vercel?
const firebaseAdminConfig = {
  privateKey: (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY as string).replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
  clientEmail: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
}

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseAdminConfig)
  });
  console.log("SET SDK");
}

This code in my layout.tsx and I got a problem at vercel
FirebaseAppError: Service account object must contain a string "project_id" property.
errorInfo: {
code: 'app/invalid-credential',
message: 'Service account object must contain a string "project_id" property.'
},
codePrefix: 'app'
I searched at google during few days but I couldn't find a solution.
(I also registered this data in vercel environments)
I am creating a website using firebase's notification function, and the code is for initializing the firebase SDK.

The error message is telling you that you need a "project_id" property in your service account credentials, but your object doesn't have one.  It has "projectId", which is not the same.
